# Prevent OS from Resizing Images with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, pixel, screen-density

Okay, so here's the issue.  I'm designing a website mockup in Photoshop (set at 72dpi).

I export a logo.png file with the width and height of: 295px x 129px.

I visit the logo.png file directly in the browser (Chrome or Firefox), and the image appears 25% larger.  I verify this by taking a screenshot and comparing them side by side.

I was wondering what the issue was, and I realized that on Windows 8 control panel (Appearance and Resolution -> Display), "Change the size of all items" is set at "Larger - 150% (default)".  I'm on 2 4k monitors.

If I change this value to 125% and log back in to the windows user, everything appears way smaller (uncomfortably smaller), but in the browser, my image now appears at the correct size.

**So my question is this..**

Is there a way to prevent the browsers from resizing my image content?  I would prefer not to hack it by specifying width:75%, for obvious reasons (those with 100% OS item scales would see it even smaller).

Comment: It isn't resizing text etc? Only the image?

Comment: I'm not sure about text being resized, but if I had to guess, probably so.